# How to read event log created in windows service app?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

I have a windows service app, where I have created eventLog object.

```
eventLog.Log = "MyLog"; // I'm not really sure what value to choose here
eventLog.Source = this.ServiceName;
```

I install the app and in VS2012 go to:

ServerExplorer -> Servers -> myDevice -> EventLogs -> MyLog

But I can't read this file. In my app I implemented FileSystemWatcher and on some event I write information into my log file. How could I access this info (needed for debugging).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to:

Component Services > Event Viewer > Application and services > MyLog.

You can find Component services by typing it in the "Start" at search area or going to

**Control Panel**, change view by into small icons select **Administrative Tools**.

**NOTE:**

I think you should change event log source and log name as below

```
eventLog.Source = "ServiceNameSource";
eventLog.Log = "ServiceNameLog"
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to use custom source do the following:

*First option:* You have to run application as administrator. Because otherwise your application won't be able to search in Security logs and it will throw SecurityException.

```
        EventLog testEventLog = this.EventLog;
        //Or if you are not using windows service, then:
        //EventLog testEventLog = new EventLog();
        testEventLog.Source = "TestServiceSource";
        testEventLog.Log = "TestServiceLog";

        //If log source doesn't exists create new one
        if (!System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(testEventLog.Source))
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(testEventLog.Source, testEventLog.Log);
        }
```

*Second option:* You don't have to run your application as administrator. But it won't search security logs.

```
        EventLog testEventLog = this.EventLog;
        //Or if you are not using windows service, then:
        //EventLog testEventLog = new EventLog();
        testEventLog.Source = "TestServiceSource";
        testEventLog.Log = "TestServiceLog";

        bool eventSourceExists = false;
        try
        {
            eventSourceExists = System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists(testEventLog.Source);
        }
        catch(System.Security.SecurityException)
        {           
            eventSourceExists = fasle;
        }

        //If log source doesn't exists create new one
        if (!eventSourceExists)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource(testEventLog.Source, testEventLog.Log);
        }
```

Comment: when i'm typing Component Services, nothing goes up( Can I access it other way somehow? You mean I need to add "Source" and "Log" to my service name or use exactly  "ServiceNameSource" and "ServiceNameLog"?

Comment: no not exactly. {ServiceName} = your service name. And consider that your source and log names should not be too long. Have you tried going to control panel > administrative tools > componenet services?

Comment: Why can't I create long names? And besides I can't assign any value to eventLog.Log cause I will get an error when trying to open the .designer. I guess I should choose between the values presented in a designer: MyLog, Application, System etc.

Comment: because only first eight characters of your source name will be considered. I will edit my answer to show you how to avoid this exception